# Remove html tag inside a javascript variable that contains an external html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to remove a div from an external html form that I'm showing in a jquery dialog box in my project.

Both webpages belong to my company, and the idea is to show the form of our issue tracking tool (which is in a different company domain) inside the main web through a dialog box, so that it only has to be filled in to instantly add an issue without having to access the tool from the outside.

So far this works (shows external form in dialog box):

```
function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            var pweb = '<object data="http://[internal domain]" width="1024px" height="768px" />';
            $("#dialog").html(pweb);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                minHeight: 768,
                minWidth:1024,
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    };
```

Now, I need to remove the div named "report_issue_header" inside that form before showing it. I've tried:

```
$("#dialog").html(pweb);
var teaser = $("#dialog").clone();
teaser.find(".report_issue_header").remove()
```

or

```
$("#dialog").html(pweb);
var teaser = $("#dialog").clone();
teaser = $.trim($(".report_issue_header", teaser).remove().end().html());
```

As I found here: [jquery remove html elements inside variable (jquery object)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269894/jquery-remove-html-elements-inside-variable-jquery-object)

But it doesnt seem to work.

I also tried this javascript:

```
pweb.getElementsByTagName("report_issue_header").remove();
```

And many similar approaches, but nothing does the trick. I admit I'm a C programmer and have very little experience with Javascript, though I'm guessing it has to do with how I manage the external code in the variable. In other examples I've seen, they just use $(this). and use jQuery and it works properly...

Comment: is "report_issue_header" the id or class of the div you're trying to remove?

Comment: a good approach when debugging javascript is to open the console to see if there is any error triggered

Comment: The class: "<div class="report_issue_header">Title</div>". But I also tried removing Id's of other elements just for the sake of trying and it didn't work either.

Comment: @FikriMarhan No errors with the jQuery approach (but the div is still there), "Uncaught error" when I try the javascript methods getElementsByTagName() and such. It was the first thing I tried hoping it would be of help :(

Comment: The use of clone will not work there - you are removing from a cloned copy of the elements, not the actual elements on the page.  However, I'm not sure it will work anyway.  The only element on your page is the object. THat said I haven't tried this with objects.  Could you alter the other page not to show the stuff you don't want in response to, say, a get param - then you append "?inline" (or whatever you have called your GET param) to the URL used as data for the object.

Comment: @Adam Of course for me it'd be easier to just modify the other tool, but I've been asked to explicitly avoid that since is not my project and it would involve other people... Modifying the object is what I need :(

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i notice is that you clone element, so what you are removing is actually the cloned element, why dont you try

```
$("#dialog").html(pweb).find(".report_issue_header").remove();
```

Comment: Just double checked it doesn't work, though I had already tried that too. About the cloning, every jQuery example that I found does it for some reason, but I did think the same and tried without it. It doesn't work anyway... Your reasoning is good though.

Comment: If you want to change elements in a variable and *not* affect the elements on the page then you need to clone them first.  You *do* want to affect the elements on the page so you don't want to clone them.