# Remove element by class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Remove some class tag from variable, not from HTML element.
I have no idea about how to describe it briefly, so see my example

HTML:

```
<div id="test" class="layout ui-resizable ui-droppable">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
    <div id="obj1" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging ui-resizable">
        <img id="imgTest" class="photo"><img>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var s = ('#test')[0]
// typeof s -> object
```

I want to remove all elements containing `ui-resizable-handle` in class name from variable s, NOT from HTML element.

After remove, HTML element still the same.

But the value of s changes to

```
<div id="test" class="layout ui-resizable ui-droppable">
    <div id="obj1" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging ui-resizable">
        <img id="imgTest" class="photo"><img>
    </div>
</div>
```

How could I do this by javascript or jQuery?

Note: jQuery is better for me

Comment: $('.ui-resizable-handle').remove()???

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón It will also remove from HTML element

Comment: $('.ui-resizable-handle').hide();???

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269894/jquery-remove-html-elements-inside-variable-jquery-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet showing an example of using the clone function that was suggested by Martin. The remove function removes all the divs with the '.ui-resizable-handle' from the original html and the console.log will display the resulting html after removal. Just run the snippet below to see the behavior.

```js
$(function(){
  var s = $('#test').clone();
  s.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();

  console.log(s.html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="test" class="layout ui-resizable ui-droppable">
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
    <div id="obj1" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging ui-resizable">
        <img id="imgTest" class="photo"><img>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: lol what, you just took my answer, without any change, and yours is accepted? :D troll level stack overlol :D

Comment: Sometimes it is helpful for new users to see examples. Snippets can be very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to have different HTML markup in the variable? You should use clone first so changes will not affect the original HTML.

```
var s = $('#test').clone();
s.find('.ui-resizable-handle').remove();

console.log(s);
```

https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that is easier to understand. We clone `#test` and loop through it to check if each child element has children. If it does, then we loop through the child to remove all elements with the class of `.ui-resizable-handle`. If it doesn't have any children, then we continue down `#test` to remove its children where they have a class of `.ui-resizable-handle`. We then print out the clone of `#test` to the end to see that we actually removed the children in memory.

```js
var copy = $("#test").clone(); // Copy of DOM

copy.children().each(function() {
  if ($(this).children().length > 0) { // Check to see if any child has children
    $(this).children().each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('ui-resizable-handle')) {
        $(this).remove(); // Grandchild removal
      }
    });
  }
  if ($(this).hasClass('ui-resizable-handle')) {
    $(this).remove(); // Child removal
  }

});

console.log($(copy)[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" class="layout ui-resizable ui-droppable">
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
  <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
  <div id="obj1" class="ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-draggable-dragging ui-resizable">
    <img id="imgTest" class="photo"><img>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
    <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```